# Is there a way to sense outgoing chat message from player? Minecraft Forge 1.16.1

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

I'm new to coding Minecraft Forge mods, and need help intercepting a chat message. It needs to be so:

1. Nobody else can see the message
2. It can reply with it's own message, or open a gui, or do something.

Comment: What research have you done so far?

Comment: well i tried searching about it, and found nothing...

Comment: wait, that's a plugin, not forge mod. also, it's server side.

Comment: ok, thanks! I'm typing more here because it won't let me type less

Comment: http://maven.thiakil.com/forge-1.12-javadoc/net/minecraftforge/client/event/ClientChatEvent.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Michael pointed out in the comments, you can use the [ClientChatEvent](https://github.com/MinecraftForge/MinecraftForge/blob/1933d05e36245ef7461b29853b4854fa769a807f/src/main/java/net/minecraftforge/client/event/ClientChatEvent.java#L44)

```java
@SubscribeEvent
public void chatMessage(ClientChatEvent event){
    ...
}
```

> ClientChatEvent is fired whenever the client is about to send a chat message or command to the server.

You can read about how to use the event bus system in the [Forge documentation](https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/1.15.x/events/intro/).